# What if there are 2 udev rule in the /etc/udev/70-xxx.rule

Tags: udev

What will happen if there are 2 udev rules within the /etc/udev/70-xxx.rule in above kernel 3.10.x?
I had 2 udev rules, the eth got named to ethx_renamed for some reason. I was wondering if this is expected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both UDEV rules will be processed.   The UDEV rules are split into multiple files for convenience only.   This is expected behaviour

What you are most likely seeing is a change in resource identifier and association between resource name and and interface id.  When the new address was discovered it was assigned a new resource.

As you are talking about ethernet addresses, it is likely the id that is different is a mac address.

Comment: Thanks for your help. By the way, does udev rule come first than ifcfg-ethxx configuration file?

Comment: It must be that way, because the configuration files require to know the interfaces they are working on - such interfaces being assigned by udev.